# How to merge/consolidate multiples xlsb files into one

Tags: excel, vbscript, merge, consolidation

I need to merge multiple xlsb files into one using vbscript, all of them have a header, but only a header of the first file is needed in this merge, headers of the other files should be ignored. Anyone has an idea how to do this?

I tried this code... it works well, but I need it to ignore the headers of the other files:

```
strPathSrc = "C:\Users\user\Documents\teste_merge\" ' Source files folder
strMaskSrc = "*.xlsb" ' Source files filter mask
iSheetSrc = 1 ' Sourse sheet index or name
strPathDst = "C:\Users\user\Documents\teste_merge\Result.xlsb" ' Destination file
iSheetDst = 1 ' Destination sheet index or name

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = True
Set objWorkBookDst = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(strPathDst)
Set objSheetDst = objWorkBookDst.Sheets(iSheetDst)
Set objShellApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objFolder = objShellApp.NameSpace(strPathSrc)
Set objItems = objFolder.Items()
objItems.Filter 64 + 128, strMaskSrc
objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
For Each objItem In objItems
    Set objWorkBookSrc = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(objItem.Path)
    Set objSheetSrc = objWorkBookSrc.Sheets(iSheetSrc)
    GetUsedRange(objSheetSrc).Copy
    Set objUsedRangeDst = GetUsedRange(objSheetDst)
    iRowsCount = objUsedRangeDst.Rows.Count
    objWorkBookDst.Activate
    objSheetDst.Cells(iRowsCount + 1, 1).Select
    objSheetDst.Paste
    objWorkBookDst.Application.CutCopyMode = False
    objWorkBookSrc.Close
Next

Function GetUsedRange(objSheet)
    With objSheet
        Set GetUsedRange = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.UsedRange.Row + .UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1, .UsedRange.Column + .UsedRange.Columns.Count - 1))
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Welcome to SOF! Please post some code or what you have tried.

Comment: i edit my question, look